# Repeat Event Calendar based - Database Design

Tags: sql-server

I have got similar question to: [How to best handle exception to repeating calendar events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2481937/how-to-best-handle-exception-to-repeating-calendar-events).

My questions is regarding the database design.

I have some event running indefinitely however sometimes the end date is known. Lets say i am creating one event to take one medicine so i know when it is going to start but i don't know when it need to be stopped, it will depend on the progress and how the doctor advises.

Now the interesting bit is, though i will be taking medicine everyday at particular time, for some day it can CHANGE (Time, Dose etc).

So, i will have one table storing the medication name, dose, start date etc.

Questions:
1. Should there be physical record for each day [As its subject to change on particular date]. But there can be millions of record if we start to store for each date.

2. Alternatively, i can have exception for the date user is changing the details.
3. Or i can create record for 6 months and when the time will get closer either user can increase or system will increase automatically if the event is still going.

I wonder how Google calendar handles repeat indefinably.

Your suggestion will be appreciated.

Pankaj.

Answer (score 2):

I'd make a table with various possible conditions:

```
table repetition (
  event_id int foreign key,
  first_date date not null,
  last_date date not null,
  day_period int null, -- 3 = every 3 days
  day_of_month int null, -- 1..31
  -- day_of_week int null, -- 0..6, if needed
  -- whatever else
)
```

Now you can easily select events that happen today:

```
select event.*
from repetition
where
  -- (day_of_week is null or day_of_week = :current_day_of_week) and
  (day_of_month is null or day_of_month = :current_day_of_month) and
  (day_period is null or (:current_date - first_date) mod day_period = 0) and
  first_date <= :current_date and
  last_date >= :current_date
join event on event.id = event_id
```

An index by (first_date, last_date) will make the query plan efficient enough (an index range scan).

To make the range 'indefinite', just put `last_date` far to the future, like year 3000.

To handle 'single' changes in events, you can add a `change_of` column to `event` table and make it refer back to `event.id`. For regular events, it is null. For change events, it stores the overriding information for the event pointed to by `change_of`. If you fetch two events for current day, and one of these has `change_of` pointing to another event, you use the data from the overriding event record, and ignore the record to which `change_of` refers. For a one-time change, `last_date` = `first_date`.

This also allows to add recurring changes, which may be useful (regular prescription every second day and a change every 14th day), and changes on changes, which you'll probably avoid by input logic or a trigger.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to be it would be best to store the time for the next event and information about how often it should be repeated.

Example:

```
Next event: 2011-02-21 08:15
Repeats: Weekly (or any other format you deem appropriate)
```

"Next event" needs to be incremented when the time comes.

To check if the event is today you check if NOW = first part of "Next event"

Comment: How do you quickly find out whether to take this medicine today?